# How can I use an exception without the script dying?

Tags: php

I'd like to use an exception for error handling in a part of my code but if the code should fail, I would like the script to continue. I want to log the error though. Can someone please help me figure this out?

---

```
try{
    if($id == 4)
    {
      echo'test';
    }
}
catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

echo'Hello, you should see me...'; <------ I never see this.. No errors, just a trace.
```

Comment: You cannot do this using exceptions, because it is built into the code. However, you could use a custom error class, or `trigger_error`

Comment: Thanks Chacha. I will look into trigger_error. Don't believe I've ever used that before.

Comment: Just a quick glance at the docs in this... It is user level and unless I can log to a file without the use seeing the message, it won't work for me.

Comment: You can use `set_error_handler` (http://php.net/set_error_handler) to deal with an error triggered by `trigger_error` ;; btw, in the code you posted, there is nothing throwing and exception...

Comment: `set_error_handler` is the other one. It allows you to create a custom function/class for dealing with errors, where you could log it. This technically cover all errors, but it is something to look at. You could always just manually call your own function `write_log_error()`.

Comment: Yes, your right, I didn't include anything... SOrry. I have an include to another file in that block. If you want, I can fetch it. Sorry, been up all night and I'm getting a bit sluggish. :)

Comment: It is very possible you could have a syntax error and aren't seeing the error, if this results in a blank page. Are you seeing anything on the page?

Comment: @Bebo, you might want to try sleeping and then coming back to it :) One of the most annoying things is trying to program without any sleep.

Comment: I agree. I sit here for countless hours and it all starts looking the same after a while. I can come back in a few hours. I'll look for you then.

Comment: I have E_ALL and E_STRICT set so I'd get everything. I honestly don't think that I have an error. So, what does "rethrowing" an exception mean?

Comment: E_ALL and E_STRICT are in the php.ini or .htaccess file right? Because PHP Syntax errors will mean that if you do a command like `error_reporting()`, it wont execute and thus the errors wont be shown.

Comment: I have them set in the ini file right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code that is *calling* the code that *may* throw an [Exception](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) do

```
try { 
    // code that may break/throw an exception
    echo 'Foo';
    throw new Exception('Nothing in this try block beyond this line');
    echo 'I am never executed';
    throw new CustomException('Neither am I');
} catch(CustomException $e) {
    // continue here when any CustomException in try block occurs
    echo $e->getMessage();
} catch(Exception $e) { 
    // continue here when any other Exception in try block occurs
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

// script continues here
echo 'done';
```

Output will be (adding line breaks for readability):

```
'Foo'                                         // echoed in try block
'Nothing in this try block beyond this line'  // echoed in Exception catch block
'done'                                        // echoed after try/catch block
```

Try/Catch Blocks may also be nested. See Example 2 in the PHP Manual page linked above:

```
try{
    try {
        throw new Exception('Foo');
        echo 'not getting here';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    echo 'bar';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
echo 'done';

'Foo'  // echoed in inner catch block
'bar'  // echoed after inner try/catch block
'done' // echoed after outer try/catch block
```

---

Further reading at DevZone:

- http://devzone.zend.com/node/view/id/666
- http://devzone.zend.com/article/679-Exceptional-Code---PART-2
- http://devzone.zend.com/node/view/id/652
- http://devzone.zend.com/article/653-PHP-101-PART-12-BUGGING-OUT---PART-2

Comment: The script inside the try statement will not continue to execute.

Comment: Excellent Gordon, thank you. I have this much already. What happens though is when there is an error (TCP/IP), the script dies. What I would like to do, because these TCP/IP errors generally correct themselves quickly is just have the script continue. However, I would like to log the error. Is this at all possible using exceptions?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are refering to with TCP/IP errors. If you mean the connection to the server dies and you want to pick it up on the next request, then no. This is impossible.

Comment: Well, if the connection dies on the first time out, log the error but continue. If it fails again, the die. Possible?

Comment: Thank you Gordon. This helps. This also looks like what I posted up top where I was trying to throw an exception on a second error. It doesn't look like it's possible though.

Comment: You can catch various types of Exceptions in a try block, but once an Exception is catched, the try block will not be continued.

Comment: Ok, and that is concrete, right? I mean, when it is said that an error can be "re-thrown", it doesn't mean that the same try block will be tried a second time. Right?

Comment: You guys have been great help. GOrdon, I'm going to give you the credit on this one because you've included the custom exception and I believe this is what I am after. I'd like to ask you a few more questions but it looks like your gone. Thanks for your help.

Comment: "Re-Thrown" in the example only means the catched exception from the inner block is thrown again and then gets catched by the outer block. If it wasnt thrown in the catch block, program flow would continue after the inner try/catch block. This might give you the level of granularity you are looking for, though I find it mind boggling to follow.

Answer (score 5):

You have to catch the exception :

```
// some code

try {
    // some code, that might throw an exception
    // Note that, when the exception is thrown, the code that's after what
    // threw it, until the end of this "try" block, will not be executed
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // deal with the exception
    // code that will be executed only when an exception is thrown
    echo $e->getMessage(); // for instance
}

// some code, that will always be executed
```

And here are a couple of things you should read :

- [Exceptions in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)
- [Exceptional PHP: Introduction to Exceptions](http://www.brandonsavage.net/exceptional-php-introduction-to-exceptions/)

Comment: The code inside the try statement will not continue to execute.

Comment: @Chacha102 : I've edited my answer to insist on that -- the solution being to put the code "that must always be excuted" after the try/catch block ;; still, this offers the ability to log the exception, and the script will continue.

Comment: Thanks Pascal, This much I already have down. I would like to log the first error and have the script continue, if possible. Is this possible?

Comment: @Pascal, I don't believe you understand the question. He wants the block inside the try statement to continue to execute.

Comment: @Bebo : the script's excution will continue after the try/catch block -- which means the try block should contain a group of statements that have to be executed as a whole (I'm thinking about a database transaction, for example)

Comment: Oh wow.. So the code that gets executed goes below the catch block.. Right?

Comment: @Pascal, I realize this is not possible, but I am simply waiting for someone to mention that :)

Comment: @Chacha102 : oh, I didn't see the question like this, I have to admit ;; @Bebo : well, that's just not the way exceptions really work ^^ ;; and yes, the code after the catch block will always be excuted (independantly of whether there's been an exception thrown or not)

Comment: Hmm. I have the same exact code that you have posted but my code dies with the errors logged as expected. Nothing below my catch block executes.

Comment: @Pascal, Of course now I'm going to look like an idiot if I am actually wrong and it was the way you perceived it.

Comment: @Bebo : that's odd ; are you sure your code is throwing an exception (and not an "error") ; and are you sure there's no `exit` nor `die` ?

Comment: Yes, 100% positive. The code throws an exception because I get the trace along with it. This was why I was wondering how to use or better phrased, why to use exceptions if they are going to kill your script.

Comment: Yes, Pascal, I only use die in my db script and it is with the mysql error attached. There is no exception in that script.

Comment: as long as your exception is catched, and you are not using exit not die in the catch block (nor have anything that raises another problem), there is no reason for your script to end... Could you edit your question, to show us more relevant code, so we can understand better ?

Comment: Sure. Pascal. I will post my exception block too.